# How to run java applications in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jnlp, java-web-start, jar-signing

I have created a simple Java application containing buttons, text fields and so on. I have created the JAR file and also the JNLP file for it and had it signed by Jarsigner.

Now I want to be able to run the java application (Java Web-Start) from a Google App Engine project. I used:

< a href="/.../mycode.jnlp">Launch application< /a>

This would work on a normal html page but does not work on my Java App Engine project which uses JSP pages. If I click the link on App Engine, it just downloads the JNLP file and doesn't run the java program.

I have searched for solutions to this to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is likely to be a MIME type issue. Try [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Changing_the_MIME_Type_for_Static_Files). The MIME type is `application/x-java-jnlp-file`.

Comment: I've set MIME type in the web.xml as:
` <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jnlp</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
</mime-mapping> `

But it still just downloads the jnlp file instead of running it

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Content-Type header is not application/x-java-jnlp-file as expected? That would determine if it's a web.xml issue or one with browser configuration.